# how to switch off mypy checking folders that do not have .py files

Tags: python, python-3.7, mypy

I've set mypy to run against /src/**/.  When this runs I get errors such as

```
There are no .py[i] files in directory 'src/repos/__pycache__/'
```

Is there a way I can ignore certain paths?
I don't want to have to specify individual paths to every folder or file.

Comment: can't you just point it at the python files rather than directories?  e.g. `src/**/*.py`?

Comment: note that it does "import discovery" by default so I just tend to point it at the root files and it'll find all the dependencies automatically

Comment: This is a repo of AWS lambda functions so there is no 'root'.
I'd like to be able to add new lambda functions without having to worry about adding it to the ini file.
Your first suggestion has worked.  src/**/*.py
I did think of this after posting the question but hadn't had a chance to try it out.  If you put as the answer I'll accept it

Comment: I don't understand your "lack of root" comment.  I presume there are a well defined set of entry points into your codebase (i.e. files containing handlers) and I'd put these into any CI scripts.   That way I can run `mypy` on the things I care about locally while having CI do the right thing.  Last time I checked, tools like `pytest` aren't annotated so `mypy` tends to bail on any tests (which seem likely to be picked up by your glob).  I tend to use the `mypy.ini` file for just making it be more "strict" by default.

Comment: As you suggest there is multiple handlers, one for each lambda.  For every new lambda I add, I would have to update mypy.ini with the path to that handler entry point.  I will likely  forget these details in the future so I'd rather just point it at the /src and include everything.  Then all new lambdas are handled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the comments, pointing mypy at the Python source files is probably the easiest option

for other people coming across this question: this "solves" the issue because of how mypy handles command line arguments.  if it's passed a directory name (as the OP had implicitly done) then it will look inside that directory for any Python files to check.  this failed because the glob happened to match directories that didn't include any `.py` files.

changing the glob to match names ending in `.py` means that it's likely to just pick up Python source files which keeps mypy happy

Comment: How would mypy be run using your suggestion here ? Is there an example of the cli argument / .ini setting ?

Comment: @baxx my first comment includes an example (`mypy src/**/*.py`) but I think I'd just use `mypy src` if at all possible.